# Question about showing that $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(XY-1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}[T,T^{-1}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, quotient-group, ring-isomorphism

I want to show that $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(XY-1) \cong \mathbb{K}[T,T^{-1}]$ and I’ve asked myself it is possible to show this by using the euclidean division of a polynomial in $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(XY-1)$?

Answer (score 0):

The isomorphism is $X \to T$, $Y \to T^{-1}$. Just try it out the details are not hard. The intuition is that in $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(XY-1)$, the relation $XY = 1$ means that $Y$ is now the multiplicative inverse of $X$ (so, serves the same purpose as $X^{-1}$).

Comment: Please do not answer questions, where not enough effort is shown. The OP asked almost the same question yesterday and has deleted it now. For a discussion on the quality
standards of this site see
[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).